# Limpar o background do fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Estou usando o [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar) para um sistema onde o usuário clica em um dia para marcar uma agenda. Preciso deixar o fundo do dia clicado com uma determinada cor e isso eu achei na documentação como fazer e é simples mesmo, o meu problema aqui é quando o usuário clica em um segundo dia, e com isso o primeiro dia clicado deveria "apagar" a cor de fundo e deixar somente o segundo dia.

Eu até fiz, mas imagino que não da melhor forma, se alguém souber de uma forma melhor para isso.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var opt = {
            dayClick : function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

            // seta todo background-color como branco
            $('.fc-view-month > table > tbody > tr > td').css('background-color', '#fff');

            // seta o background-color do dia clicado como vermelho
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    };

    $('.calendar').fullCalendar(opt);

});
```

**[Exemplo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eTMJW/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sua solução é correta. Eu acrescento outra que é preferível, por usar classes em vez de aplicar o CSS diretamente ao elemento.

```
// Remove todo background do calendário
$('.fc-view-month > table .selecionado').removeClass('selecionado');

// Adiciona a classe "selecionado" ao dia clicado
$(this).addClass('selecionado');
```

e o CSS:

```css
.selecionado {
    background-color: #f55;
    transition: background-color 80ms linear; /* Isto é só para suavizar o aparecer */
                                              /* e desaparecer do fundo */
}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/eTMJW/1/)